# mat-tab transition triggers other animations in angular material table with expandable rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations, mat-table, mat-tab

I have a screen with mat-tab-group and one tab contains a table with expandable rows, those rows will be expanded only if click on it, but issue here is it will expand all rows automatically if we change the tab  and come back . What is wrong here. ?
[image]

This will show correctly for the first time
then

[image]

it will expand all rows

[image]

Links : [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpnuku?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is because , I have to wrap mat-tab contents by

`<ng-template matTabContent> //your content goes here  </ng-template>`

Here is a working solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeveze?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.html